# What's the meaning of 2.2.5 in memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5?

Tags: c, glibc, abi, objdump

My glibc version is 2.32-5, but when I "objdump" memcpy implementation, it shows:

```
00000000000a9280 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5>:
   fe9ba:       48 8d 05 bf a8 fa ff    lea    -0x55741(%rip),%rax        # a9280 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   ffc71:       48 8d 05 08 96 fa ff    lea    -0x569f8(%rip),%rax        # a9280 <memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5>
```

What's `2.2.5` here?

Comment: Same question with an unaccepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416442/what-does-the-glibc-2-2-5-suffix-on-symbols-do

Comment: @PaulHankin Not the same question. That question asks what the meaning is of the suffix, this question asks why the version mismatch occurs.

Comment: @orlp There's more than a little overlap, since this question also literally asks "what's the meaning of 2.2.5 in memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5".

Comment: Since you seem to be looking at an x86_64 build of glibc, you will probably find that it also has `<memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14>`. The `@@` indicates that is the default implementation of `memcpy`. The `<memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5>` is an older implementation kept for compatibility with executables linked against older versions of the library.